# JavaScript array.forEach(()) -iterate, change and return new numbers in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to return an array, changeArray, with each element in "array" + 2.

I'm getting an empty "changeArray."

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function changeArray(array){
  var newNums = [];
  array.forEach(function(number){
    number = number + 2;
    console.log(number);
    //return(newNums);
  });return(newNums);
}changeArray(array);
```

Thanks Everyone for your great answers. They really help. I was expected to use .forEach and "return" the new array. I agree .map would be best, but ...  Thank you so much!!

Comment: You never put anything into newNums... and return is not a method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would be the proper tool for that job

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    
var newNums = array.map(x => x + 2);

console.log(newNums);
```

---

The reason the code isn't working, is because you can't really return from a `forEach` like that, you'd have to push to the array in each iteration

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function changeArray(array) {
  var newNums = [];
  
  array.forEach(function(number) {
    newNums.push( number + 2 );
  });
  
  return newNums;
}

var result = changeArray(array);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It would be even better if you explain why his code not working and why the return inside the `forEach` callback has no effect.

Comment: You nailed it! I simply deleted your last two lines, and called the function. It returned the new array. Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm not sure which of the two suggestions in this answer you say nailed it.  But the first one, with `map`, is clearly the better technique.  The second one serves to show what went wrong in your attempt and how to fix it.  But `map` is clearly the correct tool for this job.

Comment: Scott, I guess I should have pointed out that I didn't know how to populate the new array. For my purposes, which required me to use .forEach, the second one worked with a very small modification. Thanks for your input. It's really appreciated. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

The proper function for this task is [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) indeed.

But you can still use your function with some modification.

```js
    var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    function changeArray(inputArray){
      var newNums = inputArray.slice();
      newNums.forEach(function(number, index){
        newNums[index] = number + 2;
      });
  return(newNums);
    }
console.log(changeArray(array));
```

**Explanation**

First of all, you coded `changeArray()` to always return an empty array.

See `var newNums = [];`, then `return(newNums);`.

While you use `forEach()` against `array` variable.

Second, you should read more about `forEach()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

And if you notice, i use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to copy the values of `inputArray` into `newNums`.

It's just kind of good practice to ensure `inputArray` not modified by the function.

Comment: This code is more confusing than it should be because of the shadowing of `array`.  It would be more understandable if that parameter had a different name... and of course, as the other answer points out, `map` is the correct tool for this job.

Comment: Updated the code for clarity, thanks for pointing out @ScottSauyet